# Tomcat 5.5 - second application returs 404

Tags: tomcat, tomcat5.5

There are two versions of web application. Want to have both on one machine so I can test upgrade. If there is one of them copied to Tomcat's webapplications directory and then Tomcat is started, it works fine.

So if there is only have only

```
...webapplicatios\ROOT\...
...webapplicatios\myApp25\...
```

it works fine.

Or when there is only

```
...\webapps\ROOT\...
...\webapps\myApp26\...
```

it works fine too.

If I upload both

```
...\webapps\ROOT and
...\webapps\myApp25
...\webapps\myApp26
```

only one of the apps will work. The other one returns 404, page not found.

It's running on Windows7 and I use Tomcat 5.5. Tomcat is just default installation. Any idea what to check? How to make both running both apps?

Thank you in advance for any help. I'm beginner regarding TC.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, just for case someone need it too.

1. Full installation of Apache Tomcat.
2. Then go to your http://yourServer:port/manager/html
3. run the application if is not running.

Anyway I still do not know, why one application autostarts and other not.

When I install only one of them, it autostarts by default.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely they both have the same servlet name in their /web-inf/web.xml file. If they have the same servlet name, then Tomcat will see them as the same application and will only load/dispatch one of them.

If you need to have them both running at the same time, you'll need to change the servlet name for one or the other in this config file.

Comment: Thank your for answer. Looks like tomcat things something like this. I have changed all <servlet-name> elements in one of the apps, but it still do not autostart.

Original: <servlet-name>action</<servlet-name>

New: <servlet-name>action25</<servlet-name>

Comment: Did you also change the embedded servlet-name inside the servlet-mapping tags? If so, the only other thing I can think of is to try checking global configuration in tomcathome/config/Catalina.../*.xml maybe do a grep/find for xml files that have your servlet name in them.